# Generating Cucumber + Selenium scripts(feature + Backend Code) Using exiting production code(Maven project)

Tags: rest, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

I have an existing maven project running in production for sometime now.
I am need of introducing automation testing for this product using cucumber, selenium and rest.
I am looking into an AI based tool or any alternative way for my tech to avoid writing scripts from scratch.
Bank do have existing sahi scripts though that are quiet outdated.

Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

We have already done the POC using cucumber and selenium with all possible scenario and now trying to find a way to reduce the efforts.